# How to write log file when no need to close file in running application?

Tags: c#, file, logging

We have static class `Logger` in C#, where log file initializes at starting of application. Log files gets roll back (new log file gets created) after each *512 bytes*. Now problem is, I am not able to open current log file externally, because it is being already open in my application.

I am not able to understand how to deal with this problem. How to open currently open log file, at same time it should not harm current operations on file.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you open the current log file by using notepad?

Comment: @ShaneLu Yes, but it may not guarantee to open with current content. And it may harm other operators, like writing in log file.

Comment: @pranitkothari It will not harm writing the log file if you use the correct setting (i.e. `FileShare.Read`). See my answer bellow.

Comment: Alternatively consider using a library such as [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give you an accurate answer, I need to see the code for your logger. But I will explain the idea. Let's say the logger is using `System.IO.File.Open()` method to create/open the log file for writing. Use the overload of the `Open()` method that allows you to specify the `FileShare` parameter ([here is the link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y973b725%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) and specify `FileShare.Read` for that parameter. This will allow the applications to open the log file in read-only mode, so it will not harm the logging operation.

Answer (score 1):

Using `FileShare.ReadWrite` is crucial in your case. This should so the trick for you:

```
using (FileStream stream = File.Open("filePath", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            // do your stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 - note that you need proper `FileShare` in both programs (likely `Read` on one side, `ReadWrite` on other).

Comment: -1 This is potentially dangerous as you can accidentally overwrite the log file. The OP specifically said he did not want to harm the logging operation.

Comment: @RacilHilan to my understanding he doesn't want to block the application from writing into the file and not to protect the contents of the file from external application editing. He will have to clarify this for us in any case.

Comment: @pranitkothari And where did you say "I want to **write** to the log file using an external app"?

Comment: @pranitkothari Anyway, you can then use `FileShare.ReadWrite` like George suggested. However, bear in mind that this means that one of you will overwrite the other if they happen at the same time, and there is no way around it. You repeated that you didn't want to "harm the operation", so I'm not sure anymore what you meant by that.